# Why am I getting a `root path` error after creating Shopify App via Shopify CLI?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I am trying to get started with the Shopify CLI and am having problems getting a vanilla app installed (i.e. haven't written any code yet, only trying to get things to connect up properly).

**My Setup:**

- Rails 6.1.1
- Ruby 2.7.2
- Shopify CLI installed via Homebrew

**Actions I've Taken:**

I have used the `shopify create`, `shopify serve`, and `shopify open` commands to make a simple rails app.

When visiting the URL specified by the `shopify open` command, I get the following error:

`undefined method 'root_path' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::RoutesProxy:0x0000000124837528>`

**Screenshot:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Yzt7.png)

Any ideas what is going wrong here?